# How to get context ID and search ID

Tags: jmeter

In Jmeter, I am doing a search and every time it generates a context id,a search id and a session id. I managed to get the session id from the HTTP request and then pass it to the api call. But I don't see context id and search id anywhere and I am not able to pass it to the api. What can I do to get them?

Comment: can you please share HTTP response from which we need to extract Seach ID and Context ID. Also, share your attempts with RegExExtractor

Comment: The problem is that I don't see those in the response. I only get session Id. I see the context id and search id in fiddler. But not in jmeter.

Comment: Are the values getting generated by client-side scripts (javascript file)? that is the possibility if server not sending them

Comment: I'm not sure :(

Comment: one way is to check all the server responses,  which are sent before sending the request which contains Context ID and Search ID. if not present, then it might be client side script which is generating them. you can also confirm the same with the dev team

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129028/discussion-between-naveen-and-jane).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the chat, we learned that it `client generated value`.

suggested to use following links to solve the issue, by generating `random string/int/alphanumeric/uuid` etc. based on the data:

1. For Random Int: http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__Random
2. For Randome String (alphanumeric) : http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__RandomString
3. For Random values, defined by you: http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__RandomFromMultipleVars
4. For random UUID: http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__UUID

the function you choose, depends on what type of data that you are sending.

Comment: Used ${__UUID} to generate random UUID for Search id and __RandomString for context id. Thanks Naveen!